# Even after rooting my android mobile, internal memory showing low space?

Tags: android

Actually, I rooted my android mobile, because of internal memory space(200mb) problem. After rooted, I moved most of the application to SD card, but even it shows only 35mb internal space available. Can anyone tell me how to free internal space and occupy all files in SD card?

Comment: clear your cache. This cache used by applications

Comment: I am using LG-P500 and also frequently clearing the cache.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is not the cache.The Internal memory is occupied by ur android operating system. And using all the softwares you can not move the complete apps in memory card.A part of it remains in the internal memory and even the data of the app is also in internal memory.
example after rooting facebook is occupying only 9 mb in internal where the data is 7mb and the app size in internal is just 2 mb.